# Correct sbin-path during nginx rebuild

Tags: nginx

When I rebuilding nginx I am running these commands

```
./configure --add-module=$HOME/nginx_mod_h264_streaming-2.2.7 --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin --with-debug
make
sudo make install
```

Should the --sbin-path point to my current nginx sbin directory or the actual binary file in the sbin directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this page](http://wiki.nginx.org/ModuleFr) - It looks like it wants the nginx sbin directory - `./configure --help |grep -i 'sbin'` should yield some assistance.

Comment: Looks like binary file for me   --sbin-path=PATH                   set path to the nginx binary file

Answer (score 2):

If you run `./configure --help` and grep for `sbin-path`, it will tell you for certain, but it   specifies the directory where the `make install` procedure will put any files that would normally go in `/sbin`.